# weblogic (one nodemanager controls two machines from two differant domains)

Tags: weblogic, multiple-domains, nodemanager

i have two domains with one single nodeManager under every domain one machine connnect to the nodemanager on port 5556 but managed servers inside first machine in first domain run well otherwise the second machine that connect to same nodemanager on 5556 but from differant domain their managed servers in standby condition .........i know that problem is two machines talk on same port 5556 but from differant domains
-***

> my question is how to cancel this conflect and make nodemanager listen
>   from multiports or make port multithreading for two machines

---

Comment: Each node manager is responsible for managed servers hosted on the SAME host. What is your weblogic version ?

Comment: my weblogic version 12.2.1.3

Comment: my target to create one node manager for differant domains to be easily stop and start all managed servers from differant domains from my Admin console

Comment: WLS 12.2.1.3 provides a per domain nodemanager. So, for each domain running on the host you will have a dedicated nodemanager, listenning on a specific port.

Answer (score 0):

You have one node manager per machine in weblogic. Having the same node manager for two domains is a bad idea. Simply run two different node managers on the same machine with two different ports, each one configured on a single domain. This way you avoid any interference between the two domains. Machine resourses should not be a problem because node managers are only communication proxies.